# Highlight Specific Node in returned Query Neo4j

Tags: neo4j

How to highlight a specific node in returned query.

```
match (u:Port1)-[r:Link]-(t:Port1)
return r
```

I want to return all the nodes and relationships, with the node '270' getting highlighted. What additional query should has to be included in this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to "highlight" node(s) with specific property values in the neo4j browser, there is no way to do that (without altering your data).

The neo4j browser *can* give the nodes sharing the same label the same color. So, as a workaround, you can add the same label (say, "Highlighted") to the node(s) to which you want to color in the same way. Then, tell the browser to give nodes with that label the same color.

Comment: I want to search for only a list of nodes. They don't hold any specific label. Just imagine, there is a complex network of disease. I want to find out where the infected nodes are situated in complete complex network.

Comment: Right. I am suggesting that you add a special label to the nodes you want to highlight. If you don't want the special label to be permanent, you can just delete it when you are done visualizing.